# Mediawiki - Display text inside a link

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I have this link:

```
[[user1 | Foo:555-5555]]
[[user2 | Bar:555-5556]]
```

On each user page I have:

```
===UserName===

==PhoneNumber==
```

I want to make the link become automatic, something like this:

```
[[user1 | UserName:PhoneNumber]]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You could look into [Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki).

Comment: It was not what I was looking for, but it really did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a wiki entrance query, but using Semantic from MediaWiki as sugested by Tgr, it did the trick.